# AngularJS 1.4: How to create two-way binding using bindToController and controllerAs syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controlleras

Okay, this is really bugging me. I have a directive with isolate scope, using the `controllerAs` syntax and `bindToController`:

```
function exampleDirectiveFactory() {
    var bindings = {
        foo: '=',
        bar: '@'
    }

    return {
        bindToController: true,
        controller      : 'ExampleController',
        controllerAs    : 'vm',
        scope           : bindings,
        template        : 'foo = {{ vm.foo }}<br />bar = {{ vm.bar }}'
    };
}
```

Assuming a usage like this:

```
<example foo="FOO" bar="BAR"></example>
```

...I expect the value of `vm.foo` to be two-way bound to the value of the `foo` attribute. Instead, it is `undefined`.

The value of `vm.bar` is equal to the attribute value `bar` of the HTML element, which I expect.

When I try to change the value of `vm.bar` using a filter, no change persists.

When I store the filtered value of `vm.bar` to a new variable, `vm.baz`, that works as expected.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/bn64dLx0/)

So my question has two parts:

A) Why is the value of `vm.foo` undefined when using `'='`?

B) Why can't I change the value of `vm.bar` in the scope of the controller, even if that change does not propagate to the HTML element attribute (which it shouldn't, because I'm using `'@'`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1.4 changed how bindToController works.  Though it appears that angular's documentation is still referring to the field as `true`/`false`.  Now it can accept an object just like the `scope` attribute where the attributes indicate what you want bound and how to bind it.

```
function exampleDirectiveFactory() {
    var bindings = {
        foo: '=',
        bar: '@'
    }

    return {
        bindToController: bindings, //<-- things that will be bound
        controller      : 'ExampleController',
        controllerAs    : 'vm',
        scope           : {}, //<-- isolated scope
        template        : 'foo = {{ vm.foo }}<br />bar = {{ vm.bar }}'
    };
}
```

In addition, in your fiddle, FOO is `undefined` on the parent scope, so when it binds, it will pull that `undefined` into the directive's bound controller's scope.

Further reading:
One major thing that this new `bindToController` syntax allows is the ability for the directive to not be an isolated scope and still identify what to bind.  You can actually set scope to `true` on your directive to have a new child scope that will inherit from it's ancestors.

Comment: thanks for your response. I did read about the changes to `bindToController` in 1.4 and experimented with that syntax as well. But according to your answer, or my understanding of it, this should result in `vm.foo` equalling `MAIN.FOO` and it does not: http://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/r4esw0a0/

Comment: You are referencing the scoped variable `FOO` in your directive (via `foo="FOO"` attribute on your element).  You must define `FOO`. http://jsfiddle.net/r4esw0a0/2/.  Also, you should not name all of the controllers as `vm` that defeats the purpuse of controllerAs.  http://jsfiddle.net/r4esw0a0/3/

Comment: I'm starting to see what's going on here. By using `'='`, I am implying that the value of the attribute is a variable name, not a string literal...apposed to when I use `'@'`, which binds the string value of the attribute. But why then am I not able to change the value of the bound `vm.foo` or `vm.bar` values in this example? http://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/960zLavt/

Comment: With two-way binding you must have an assignable variable to bind, using an expression with a string is not assignable. To make it more obvious: what you are doing would be similar to trying to bind to `foo="1+1"`... sure, it equals 2 which is the one-way binding but how would two-way binding set a value back to `foo`? https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=%27FOO%27&p1=example

Comment: Thanks for talking through it with me. These comments do a better job of answering my question...you may want to copy them into the answer for visibility. That said, I'll accept and really appreciate the help. Cheers!

Comment: What worked for me is to mark scope: true in directive when using bindToController. It allows two-way binding.